# Integrating a conditional between += (and possibly a challenge for math whizzes) for a matrix iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, math, matrix, iterator

I have a question and potentially a math challenge. I have a template class `Matrix` with dynamic data storage (meaning there is only one template parameter for the type).

I am storing the matrix data as a `std::vector` in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), and am writing a column iterator for it that will go down one column, start at the top of the next, go down that, and continue (the row iterator is trivial, since that is just the iterator for the `std::vector`). For incrementation/decrementation for a random-access iterator, I use a private `advance` function to avoid code duplication between `operator`s. It looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::col_iterator::advance(std::ptrdiff_t movement) { // defaulted to movement = 1 in header
    _ptr += movement * _shiftFactor;
    if (ge(_ptr, _start + _l)) {
        _currCol++; // increments column count
        _ptr = _start + (_currCol < _shiftFactor ? _currCol : _l); // moves pointer to the top of the column, or to the end if there are no more columns
    }
}
```

To give some context, the `ge()` part is actually calling an `operator()` on the static functor `std::greater_equal<T*>`, `_ptr` is a pointer to the current position of the iterator, `_shiftFactor` is the number of columns of the matrix (n), `_start` is the starting point of the vector (this doesn't change), and `_l` is the size of the **whole** data vector. Okay, I think a graphic would be nice to understand this.

Suppose I have a `Matrix<int> A` that looks like this:

```
Element: 1 2 3 4
Index:   0 1 2 3
----------------
Element: 5 6 7 8
Index:   4 5 6 7
----------------
Element: 9 1 2 3
Index:   8 9 10 11
----------------
Element: 4 5 6 7
Index:   12 13 14 15
----------------
```

where `Index` is the index that the corresponding element is stored in the `std::vector<int>`. Looking at my `advance` function, I have it so that whenever it is called (e.g.

```
template<typename T>
inline typename Matrix<T>::col_iterator &Matrix<T>::col_iterator::operator++() {
    advance(); // remember movement is defaulted to 1
    return *this;
}
```

or

```
template<typename T>
inline typename Matrix<T>::col_iterator &Matrix<T>::col_iterator::operator+=(std::ptrdiff_t movement) {
    advance(movement);
    return *this;
}
```

), then what will happen is that the `_ptr` will, for the `operator++` case, jump to the first element of the next row. So, one call of ++ will result in it at index 4, another will result at index 8, so on. And, as you see, if you keep on going until you get to 12 and try calling ++ again, the if statement will catch it (since 12 + 4 > 15) and it'll jump to index 1 and continue to 5, 9, 13, then to 2, etc. It'll get to index 15, and then the ternary will set the pointer to index "16" which is outside of the vector, which is actually `Matrix<T>::col_end()` (not shown).

However, therein lies the problem. See, for `operator++` it works **perfectly**, because `movement = 1` so the if happens once every call, so it checks whether `_ptr` is at a valid position every time. But when you extend it for `operator+=`, there is the problem. The way that I am doing it, I have `_ptr = movement * _shiftFactor`, so supposedly by adding multiples of `_shiftFactor` it should skip `movement` amount of rows. The `movement` can potentially shift the `_ptr` by an amount large enough to land **far** above `_start + _l`, but it only counts as one increment—to the top of the next column. The problem arises because **the if is only called *ONCE* after** `_ptr` **is incremented by all of ** `movement * _shiftFactor`.

Imagine this scenario. `movement = 5` and I call `operator+=` when _ptr is at index 12 (i.e. I have some `Matrix<int>::col_iterator ci` with it currently pointing to index 12 and I try to do `ci += 5`). The resulting `_ptr` value (`_ptr += 5 * 4`) is **way** above the max index, but the function doesn't know by how much. So, it simply sees that it is greater, and sets the index value at the next one, 1. But it should be at index 2, because `ci += 5` implies that it skips indices 1, 5, 9, 13 and lands on 2!! I stress this point: the if is only called once, where in reality it should be called every `_shiftFactor` increment.

Now, the superficial solution for integrating the if between each successive row increment is to do it in a for loop, like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::col_iterator::advance(std::ptrdiff_t movement) { // defaulted to movement = 1 in header
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::abs(movement); i++) {
        _ptr += static_cast<int>(std::copysign(1, movement)) * _shiftFactor; // always is either _ptr += _shiftFactor or _ptr += -_shiftFactor
        if (ge(_ptr, _start + _l)) {
            _currCol++;
            _ptr = _start + (_currCol < _shiftFactor ? _currCol : _l);
        } // this conditional is checked every time a row increments
    } // all of this is effectively a movement * _shiftFactor with the if between each increment
}
```

and that would work fine. **But**, it is **O(**`movement`**)**, which is just too unsatisfying to ignore even for an operation as trivial as this, compared to the O(1) time with the multiplication!! There has to be a simpler way to do this, right?

Sorry for the essay, but I really wanted to make sure that I covered everything. My question, potentially to you math whizzes out there: **how can I make this O(1) again while still having the if go between every row increment?** Maybe something with counting the magnitudes of `_shiftFactor` above `_start + _l`? Maybe some mod magic? Help!

Thanks!

Comment: imho more code and less text would help to understand the question. I read it all, but I didnt really get what your `operator+=` is actually supposed to do, nor what the problem is you are trying to solve

Comment: @user463035818, the problem itself is simple: OP wants to create an iterator along columns of a matrix that is stored in a row-major order. Suppose `ptr` points at the element with index `ind_ptr`, then the question is how to compute the index of the element that is pointed at by `ptr + n` for arbitrary `n`, taking into account an overflow that signals the end of traversal. OP, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Evg hm ok, I think i got it, unfortunately I have to work now ;)

Comment: @Evg That is exactly right. Thank god someone understands my cryptic writing!

Comment: @user463035818 I've added more text (sorry) that hopefully can clarify some things.

Comment: I have difficulty to understand exactly where the problem is. If we consider indices, an element can be located either by its index `k` in the vector, or by a pair `i, j`, where `i` is the row and `j` the column. Calculating `k`from `i, j` or the inverse is very easy. So if we increment `k`by a given value, it is easy to calculate the new `i, j` position. I tried to transpose this method in your code but honestly I am lost a little bit in it. Could you explain why such a simple method cannot be adapted here?

Comment: @Damien The problem is that I'm not relying on the conventional way of traversing the vector by using a defined order, e.g. the system knows how to traverse a vector by going element by element (which translates to, simply, `*(_ptr + i)`. It is subtle, but I am actually changing the `_ptr` value, AND THEN checking it against the bounds of the vector. I have no way to calculate an `i, j` from a `k` or vice versa because it would be outside the vector. If you have a way to traverse it column-wise without the `ge()` check, I welcome it.

Comment: It is not clear why you can't decompose the linear index `ptr` into the corresponding `(i, j)` pair. 1) `ptr` -> `(i, j)`, 2) compute new `(i, j)`, 3) `(i, j)` -> `ptr`. This is probably not the most efficient way to compute the new index, but the simplest and the clearest one.

Comment: @Evg Hmm...forgive me, but how would you write it?

Comment: is using division and modulus out-of-scope by choice?

Comment: `k = j + i*ncol`, `j = k % ncol`, `i = k / ncol`

Comment: After Caleth's answer I doubt there exists a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Evg I've added a semi-mathematical answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion to convert to `row, column` pair, increment `column`, convert back

```
template<typename T>
auto Matrix<T>::col_iterator::get_index(std::ptrdiff_t offset)
{
    return std::make_pair(offset / n_cols, offset % n_cols); 
}

template<typename T>
auto Matrix<T>::col_iterator::get_offset(std::pair<std::ptrdiff_t, std::ptrdiff_t> index)
{
    return index.first + index.second * n_rows; 
}

template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::col_iterator::advance(std::ptrdiff_t movement) 
{
    auto index = get_index(_ptr - _start);

    index.second += movement;
    index.first += (index.second / n_cols); // carry
    index.second %= n_cols; // wrap

    _ptr = get_offset(index) + _start;
}
```

Comment: I like this carry-wrap stuff that avoids unnecessary computations of a linear index as an intermediate step.

Comment: @Evg would it be better to have these two functions `get_index` and `get_offset` as private member functions of the Matrix class in general and then have the iterator store a pointer to the Matrix, or keep it in the iterator? Because I already have `operator[]` in the Matrix class that returns a proxy so I can simulate `operator[][]`.

Comment: @JonathanLee, if they are used in the `Matrix` class too, I'd probably move them there. Whether the iterator should store a pointer to the `Matrix` rather than copies of some of its members is debatable. Optimizer might not be able to produce good code if there are indirections. If you want fast iterator you should compare different approaches by looking at the assembly code and measuring the performance. If you decide to keep `n_rows` and `n_cols` in the iterator, consider a third option - make these functions free functions (probably in some internal `namespace`).

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way to do it (partially) that borrows the same logic as @Evg, @Damien, and @Caleth's solution, but keeps everything in a linear index. I don't know if this is more efficient or less, but here it is.

```
template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::col_iterator::advance(std::ptrdiff_t movement) {
    _ptr += movement * _shiftFactor;
    std::ptrdiff_t mag = std::floor((_ptr - (_start + _l)) / static_cast<double>(_shiftFactor));
    std::size_t rows = _l / _shiftFactor;
    if (mag >= 0) {
        _currCol += mag / rows + 1;
        _ptr = _start + (_currCol < _shiftFactor ? _currCol + mag % rows * _shiftFactor: _l);
    }   
}
```

(`mag` stands for magnitude above the threshold).

It works for both `operator++` and arbitrary `operator+=`. **However**, it still unfortunately does not work with `operator--` or `operator-=` because of the way that I set it up (particularly, in some places `_start + _l` needs to be changed to `_start`, etc. etc.). So I have spawned a new problem, and if I could work on it some more and fix that I would, but I have other more important  things to do. If you all could find the solution I'd greatly appreciate it too.